# How can I change the anchor position dynamically in Material-UI Popover when element is near the edge of the window or bottom of the page?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

when div element is at the right bottom corner of the window:
anchor-position: vertical(top)-horizontal(right)
transform-origin: vertical(bottom)-horizontal(right)

when div element is the left side of the window:
anchor-position: vertical(bottom)-horizontal(left)
transform-origin: vertical(top)-horizontal(left)

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220054/material-ui-tooltip-is-not-shown-correctly-inside-a-container-with-overflow-scro/64220678#64220678 - MUI uses popper.js - you can use `preventOverflow` modifier for your scenario

Comment: its working now. thanks.